# Array subscript is not an integer

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, int

```
int i;

va_list objects_list;
va_start(objects_list, objects);
for (id o = objects, i = 0; o != nil; o = va_arg(objects_list, id), i++);
objectsInArray = malloc(sizeof(id) * i);
va_end(objects_list);

// ... (malloc NULL checking is here, does not involve i)

va_start(objects_list, objects);
for (id o = objects, i = 0; o != nil; o = va_arg(objects_list, id), i++) {
  objectsInArray[i] = o;
}
va_end(objects_list);
```

I am getting an `Array subscript is not an integer` error on the `objectsInArray[i] = o;` line. `objectsInArray` is declared as `id *objectsInArray`.

`i` is an `int`, so why am I getting this error and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is of type `id` within the for loop. To resolve the ambiguous syntax, declare `id o` outside of the `for(...)` statement.

In Xcode, under project settings, enable the warnings for "Hidden local variables", so the compiler will warn for such things. Otherwise, when using `gcc`, use `-Wshadow`.

Comment: @Radek: I added a suggestion to make the compiler warn about this type of bug.

Comment: @Radek: I don't. If you're using `gcc`, you can use `-Wshadow` to enable the same warnings.

Answer (score 2):

No, you've created a new `i` which is of type `id`.  Unfortunately, there is no way of doing "mixed-mode" initialisation in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (id o = objects, i = 0; o != nil; o = va_arg(objects_list, id), i++)
```

includes the declaration

```
id o = objects, i = 0;
```

which means `i` is not an `int`, but an `id`. Declare `o` before the loop:

```
id o;
for (o = objects, i = 0; o != nil; o = va_arg(objects_list, id), i++)
```